# Opening two separate Selenium Chrome windows/drivers

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to open two Selenium-controlled Chrome windows:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) "
"Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36")

driver_0 = uc.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
driver_0.get(link)

driver_1 = uc.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
driver_1.get(link)
```

For some reason, this opens 2 tabs in the same window. Any idea why? How can I get two separate Chrome windows to open?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `send_keys` command to open a new browser the same way you would if you were manually accessing the website:

```
body = driver_0.find_element_by_tag_name('body')
body.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'n')
```

Use command key instead of control if on Mac.

Comment: Thanks. If I used the above, does that create a new window within driver_0? How would I control that? Or are you saying somehow it automatically goes to driver_1?

Comment: Could use another key shortcut, which again varies based on which OS you have. Im on Mac, and command-tab will switch between windows, so I send those keys.